# checkboxes not styled after ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a script file scripts.js with a function that styles all checkboxes in page. This file is referenced in the master page.

There is a user control and a aspx test page for it. On page load, the UC shows a list of checkboxes and the style is applied.

On clicking a button, an ajax call gets a list from database and binds some more checkboxes to the page. But for the new checkboxes, the style is not applied. What could be going wrong.

**scripts.js:**

```
function selectcheckBtn() {   
    alert(1); 
    if ($("input:checkbox").prev("span").length === 0) {
        alert(2); 
        $("<span class='uncheked'></span>").insertBefore("input:checkbox")
    }
    $("input:checkbox").click(function () {
        check = $(this).is(":checked");
        if (check) {
            $(this).prev("span").addClass("cheked").removeClass("uncheked")
        } else {
            $(this).prev("span").addClass("uncheked").removeClass("cheked")
        }
    });
    $("input:checked").prev("span").addClass("cheked").removeClass("uncheked")
}
```

**ctrl.ascx:**

```
<script>
function ShowMore() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/_layouts/15/handlers/ShowMore.ashx",            
            data: {},
            success: function (msg) {    
//append new chkbox list to existing list. It is hidden at first and later faded in.               
                $(".divList").append(msg); 
                    selectcheckBtn();
                    $(".hideDiv").fadeIn(300).removeClass("hideDiv");                    
                },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("An error occurred while processing your request");                
            }
        });
    }

</script>
<a href="javascript:;" id="btnMore" runat="server" onclick="ShowMore();">Show more </a>
```

On page load both alerts pop. But on clicking 'Show More', only alert(1) pops.

There are no errors in browser console.

**Rendered HTML:**

```
//with style applied to chkboxes on page load
<div><span class="uncheked"></span><input type="checkbox" runat="server"  id="406">
<label>Compare</label></div>

//with no style applied to new chkboxes
<div><input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="618"><label>Compare</label></div>
```

Comment: You've wrote several times 'cheked' instead of 'checked' could this be the reason?

Comment: No that itsn't. Im sure. This is how it was defined in the function and it works fine in page load.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand why the if condition wasn't true in `selectcheckBtn();`, for the new chkboxes. So, added a new class for the checkboxes and wrote this workaround.
Now calling this function instead of `selectcheckBtn();` in the ajax code, worked.

```
function StyleCheckBox() {
        $(".chkBx").each(function () {
            if ($(this).prev("span").length === 0) {
                $("<span class='uncheked'></span>").insertBefore($(this));
            }            
            $("input:checkbox").click(function () {
                check = $(this).is(":checked");
                if (check) {
                    $(this).prev("span").addClass("cheked").removeClass("uncheked")
                } else {
                    $(this).prev("span").addClass("uncheked").removeClass("cheked")
                }
            });
            $("input:checked").prev("span").addClass("cheked").removeClass("uncheked")
        });        
    }
```